# All the items are laterally inverted

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I just imported a flex project using Flash Builder 4 (With Eclipse). The project runs fine but all the windows, labels and other elements are laterally inverted. [image]

What's wrong?

-- I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4 plugin on eclipse

Comment: It must be your IDE settings.

Comment: Do you have the `-rtl` (Right to Left) Eclipse option set or you using Eclipse with a language where this is the default (Arabic for example).

Comment: why don't you use adobe flash builder.... easy solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting layout direction in th mxml file did the trick

```
layoutDirection="ltr"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to window of the menu bar and reset perspective....

Answer (score 0):

set following code layout direction in the application

```
layoutDirection="ltr"
```